# the annotation @CrossOrigin("*") not work

Tags: java, angular, cors

I had the error "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/products/getPro' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" while I have added the annotation @CrossOrigin("*") in my spring boot application

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
@CrossOrigin("*")
 public class ProductController {

  @Autowired
  private ProductService productService;

 @PostMapping(value = "/getPro", consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = 
    {"application/json"})
 public ResponseEntity<?> getPro(@RequestBody Product product){
    return this.productService.getPro(product);
  }
```

In my Frontend I have :

```
export class ProductService {
  public productModel : Product 
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081';
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getPro () {
  return this.http.post<Product>(this.baseUrl + "/products/getPro", 
   JSON.stringify(this.productModel));
  }
  }
```

Can anyone help me ?

**PS :I am using this application like a feign client I mean in reality I am calling another application with FeignClient ! It can be the problem ?**

Comment: Are you using spring security ? + Why do you have in spring "/getProductsData" and in angular "/getPro" ?

Comment: @Roronoa_D._Law No

Comment: OKay, how about the url "/getPro" then

Comment: @Roronoa_D._Law it was a little mistake ! edited my post take a look

Comment: Is the failing request an OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to get rid of `@crossOrigin`.

You can do following in your config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");// Your allowed paths here
    }
}
```

I will recommend you to move that all to angular only by using reverse proxy.

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8081",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

See github project here. https://github.com/vohra01/parking-demo-SG/blob/master/IdeaProjects/parking-demo/parking-ui-app/proxy.conf.json